# react native text box above scrollable-tab-view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-scrollable-tabs

New to react native, trying to place text-box above scrollable tab view

```
 export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return 
    <View>
    <TextInput
          style={{height: 50}}
          placeholder="Enter!"
          onChangeText={(searchText) => this.setState({searchText})}/>
    <ScrollableTabView
      style={{marginTop: 10, }}
      initialPage={1}
      renderTabBar={() => <FacebookTabBar />} 
      >   
      <ScrollView tabLabel="ios-search" style={styles.tabView}>
        <View style={styles.card}>
           <TextInput
          style={{height: 50}}
          placeholder="Enter!"
          onChangeText={(searchText) => this.setState({searchText})}/>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </ScrollableTabView>
    </View>
     ;
  },  
});
```

Scrollable tab view doesn't show up with above code, I am unable to understand why, please advice. I am trying to make something like Linkedin app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<ScrollableTabView>` is styled with `flex: 1`, so you need to explicitly set `flex: 1` to its parent like this in order to show it:

```
return (
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    ...
  </View>
);
```

Here is a quote from React Native [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width.html#flex-dimensions) regarding Flex:

> A component can only expand to fill available space if its parent has
>   dimensions greater than 0. If a parent does not have either a fixed
>   width and height or flex, the parent will have dimensions of 0 and the
>   flex children will not be visible.